# Upload progress bar using session.upload_progress

Tags: php, html, session

Implemented progress bar using session.upload_progress, Worked fine for some days.
But now since past 2 days it's not working, after debugging found that in  progress.php script $key is not set.Looked for solutions here[SO] but couldn't find.

> progress.php:

```
session_start();
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . "uform";
if (!empty($_SESSION[$key])) {
    $current = $_SESSION[$key]["bytes_processed"];
    $total = $_SESSION[$key]["content_length"];
    echo $current < $total ? ceil($current / $total * 100) : 100;
}
else {
    echo 80;
}
```

It's returning 80 only.

> Form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="uform" name="<?php echo ini_get("session.upload_progress.name"); ?>">
<input class="form-control input-lg file" name="presentation"  type="file" required  /></div>
```

Firing progress.php by js.
Devtools snap: [progress response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no7Li.png)

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

Could you please check your php.ini file whether upload progress is enabled or not

```
session.upload_progress.enabled = On
```

Then, if still problem persists

Try to use below while building your $key

```
$key = ini_get("session.upload_progress.prefix") . $_POST[ini_get("session.upload_progress.name")];
```

Comment: Could you please display of $_POST